# "Acciderba!", "accidempoli!" e "accipicchia!" come eufemismi di "Accidenti!"

Tags: word-usage, interjections

Leggendo l'[articolo del vocabolario Treccani sull'interiezione "accidenti!"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/accidenti/), sono stata stupita dalla frase

> «è spesso alterato eufemisticamente in *acciderba!*, *accidempoli!*, *accipicchia!*»

prima perché l'esclamazione "accidenti!" non mi è mai sembrata tanto volgare per necessitare un eufemismo e poi perché non sapevo dell'esistenza di queste interiezioni (*acciderba!*, *accidempoli!* e *accipicchia!*). Per questa ragione, vi chiedo:

1. L'interiezione "accidenti!" è considerata un volgarismo?
2. *Acciderba!*, *accidempoli!* e *accipicchia!* sono interiezioni comunemente usate attualmente?

Comment: Aggiungo "acciderboli".

Comment: @martina: Tutte queste interiezioni mi sembrano molto divertenti! :-D

Comment: Io uso abbastanza spesso *accipicchia*. Devo dire che questo tipo di interiezioni ormai sono spesso soppiantate, specialmente dai giovani, da termini volgari tipo *cazzo*. Sinceramente trovo questo tipo di linguaggio molto povero e fastidioso; preferisco i termini desueti.

Comment: Adesso ho visto anche "*accicoria!*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Non è assolutamente un volgarismo. È piuttosto da considerarsi un po' obsoleto semmai. Probabilmente si considera offensivo perchè sottointende "ti vengano" o "ti auguro", come nella simile espressione "accidenti a te" in cui si augurano appunto degli accidenti.

2) Non sono mai usate se non ironicamente, a parte "accipicchia" che in effetti ancora ogni tanto ho sentito.

Comment: A complemento di quello che spiega wanted2help, gli eufemismi non si usano solo per evitare termini volgari in senso stretto (per esempio triviali o scatologici), ma anche per evitare di menzionare eventi negativi (morte, malattie) o enti sovrannaturali (“cribbio” al posto di “Cristo”, “perdinci” al posto di “per Dio” etc.) o, come in questo caso, per attenuare una sorta di maledizione.

Comment: Sembra che queste interiezioni siano cadute piuttosto in disuso, ma in questi link ci sono interessanti testimonianze di come erano usate nel passato: http://www.lua.it/dizionario/?cat=17, http://www.lua.it/dizionario/?cat=18, http://www.luigiceccarelli-ceccarius.it/scritti/pdf/beltempo.pdf