# Come e quando si usa l'avverbio "semmai"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Questa domanda mi è stata suggerita da questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/3795/707). Là ho letto

> «È piuttosto da considerarsi un po' obsoleto ***semmai***.»

Non riesco a capire quali siano gli usi dell'avverbio "semmai". Potreste spiegarmeli?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Semmai" è simile a "casomai" e "tutt'al più". In generale, si usa quando si parla di condizioni in cui dovrebbero verificarsi casi o eventi ipotetici o improbabili. Normalmente si può omettere e la frase conserva il suo significato ed è ugualmente comprensibile, anche se perde un po' di forza.

Probabilmente la spiegazione più facile è attraverso alcuni esempi.

> Non pago 10 euro per un film così brutto. Semmai è il cinema che dovrebbe pagarmi per vederlo.

Se, per qualche strano caso del destino, dovessi/volessi guardare questo film (evento comunque già di per sé improbabile), sarebbe il cinema che dovrebbe pagarmi per farlo, non viceversa.

> Non è assolutamente un volgarismo. È piuttosto da considerarsi un po' obsoleto semmai.

(A me suona meglio: "è semmai, piuttosto, da considerarsi un po' obsoleto")

Non è un volgarismo. Se proprio volessimo dire qualcosa, anche se poco importante, potremmo dire al massimo che è obsoleto.

> Non capisco perché ti lamenti. Qui semmai chi dovrebbe lamentarsi è Mario.

Se c'è qualcuno che ha motivo di lamentarsi (anche se non lo fa), quello è Mario, certamente non tu.

Un'altra maniera di interpretarlo è sostituire "semmai" con "se mai" + la parte sottintesa (solo a scopo esplicativo; in pratica, quasi sempre, farlo implica cambiamenti nella frase). Con "se mai" si indicano eventi improbabili o sconosciuti; in questo caso il "mai" è semplicemente un rafforzativo del "se":

> Se mai dovessi riuscire a dimagrire fino a 70 Kg, dovrei ringraziare il medico.

Nel caso in cui ci riuscissi, dovrei ringraziare il medico.

Quindi i nostri esempi potremmo anche interpretarli come:

> Non pago 10 euro per un film così brutto. Semmai è il cinema che dovrebbe pagarmi per vederlo -> Se mai (nel caso in cui) dovessi vederlo, sarebbe il cinema che ...
>
> Non è un volgarismo. Se mai (nel caso in cui) volessimo dire qualcosa, potremmo piuttosto dire che è da considerarsi un po' obsoleto.
>
> Se mai (nel caso in cui) ci fosse qualcuno che ha diritto a lamentarsi, quello sarebbe Mario.

Comment: Il tuo esempio fammi sembra che lo stesso di inglese "... If anything it is the cinema who should pay me to watch!"

Comment: Si esatto, o anche "if at all" (a seconda del contesto).

Comment: Interessante, grazie. :)